# Unparsable Date with colon-separated timezone

Tags: java, parsing, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying to parse this String

> 2014-04-04T14:28:38+02:00

It should be ISO 8601 format. But i can't parse it to a correct Date.
I've tried the following:

```
   String example = "2014-04-04T14:28:38+02:00"
   public final static SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz")
   Date tempDate = df.parse(example)
```

But I get always the message "unparseable Date"
I can not change the example because it's a value from a webservice.

Could it be there is a probleme with "+02:00" instead of "+0200" ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: For new readers to the question I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from Java7, to handle +02:00, you can use the following format:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ssXXX"
```

This can be seen in the [SimpleDateFormat documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 2):

## *java.time*

The modern date-time API is based on [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Dates) and thus, you do not need to use a parser (e.g. `DateTimeFormatter`) explicitly in order to parse the given date-time string as it is already in ISO 8601 format.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.util.Date;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2014-04-04T14:28:38+02:00");
        System.out.println(odt);

        // In case you need java.util.Date
        Date date = Date.from(odt.toInstant());
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-04-04T14:28:38+02:00
```

Learn more about the the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

The ISO8601 date format can be most easily parsed using [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html) which can be use as a library.

It seems that a form of Joda Time got into Java 8 as [JSR310](http://blog.joda.org/2009/11/why-jsr-310-isn-joda-time_4941.html) but I have not worked with it.